# Regex: Find value between two sections

Tags: regex

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I want to get the adress-data between the values: Kunde: XXXXX   and  Artikel:
I want to get it within the newlines for there I can use it exact like shown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH6x3.png)

Can you give me a hint, how to use the right Regex?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?s)(?<=Kunde:).*?(?=Artikel:)
```

From the image you sent this is the correct way of doing it.

(?s) may not work in your REGEX flavor. It's called "dot-all" (see how to turn on DOTALL in various languages).

I used lookbehind (?<=) and look ahead (?=) so that "Kunde:" and "Artikel:" is not included in the match.

Comment: Just for reference `(?s)` is the `/s` modifier, some languages allow to define modifiers like `g` or `m` and you can use it to define also `s`

Comment: Exactly @Nick and I forgot to mention why I'm adding (?s) to the REGEX, it's because according to your screenshot you have newline between "Kunde" and "Artikel" and without the dotall you won't watch what between your words.